# Can I get ip lease from DHCP router for linux virtual interface?

Tags: linux-networking, dhcp, vlan, mikrotik, debian-buster

I have a mikrotik router that acts as a DHCP server. I created some virtual interface on my raspberry pi using :

```
 interface eth0:1
static ip_address=192.168.88.5/24
static routers=192.168.88.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.88.1

interface eth0:2
static ip_address=192.168.88.10/24
static routers=192.168.88.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.88.1

interface eth0:3
static ip_address=192.168.88.12/24
static routers=192.168.88.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.88.1

interface eth0:4
static ip_address=192.168.88.13/24
static routers=192.168.88.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.88.1
```

Though I can ping them, but they are not visible in my routers DHCP lease list. Can I make them appear as a real device on my router?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You have set static IPs. A DHCP table will hold information about DHCP leases, which you aren't using for these.

They are most definitely considered "a real device" as is evidence by the fact you can ping them.

If you want them to show leases, you could perhaps look into using DHCP reservations for them instead - they would request an IP via DHCP still, but the router would always supply the same IP.